# Dynamic jQuery 'add a textbox' to an asp:Repeater using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm having problems with a chunk of code that's meant to add a textbox to a Repeater in ASP.

I have the following:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="uxRolesList" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
               <div id="<%# GetRolesDivId() %>" class="div_row">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="uxTxtBoxRole" runat="server" rows="5" columns="100" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RequirementDescription") %>' TextMode="multiline" MaxLength="2000"></asp:TextBox>
                    <input type="button" style="vertical-align:top;" value="X" class="remove-roles-btn" />                           
                    <br /><br />
               </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Which generates a load of textboxes that look like this in the html:

```
<td id="rolesColumn">                
    <div id="roles-0" class="div_row">
         <textarea name="ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl00$uxTxtBoxRole" rows="5" cols="100" id="ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl00_uxTxtBoxRole">Cool Job1</textarea>
        <input type="button" style="vertical-align:top;" value="X" class="remove-roles-btn" />                           
        <br /><br />
     </div>                    
 </td>
```

I've also added the following button, that should add a textbox to this list when hit:

```
 <asp:Button CssClass="btn" ID="uxAddRoleBtn" runat="server" Text="Add a new role requirement" />
```

Using the following jQuery code:

```
$("#ctl00_mainContent_uxAddRoleBtn").live("click", (function (e) {
        var rolesCounter = $('#ctl00_mainContent_uxTxtBoxRolesCount').val();

        if (rolesCounter < 10) {
            var rolesCounterText = "0" + rolesCounter;
        } else {
            var rolesCounterText = rolesCounter;
        }                     

        $('#rolesColumn').append("<div id='roles-" + rolesCounter + "' class='div_row'><textarea name='ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl" + rolesCounterText + "$uxTxtBoxRole' rows='5' cols='100' id='ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl" + rolesCounterText + "_uxTxtBoxRole' MaxLength='2000' ></textarea><input type='submit' name='ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl" + rolesCounterText + "$uxRemoveRoleBtn' value='X' id='ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl" + rolesCounterText + "_uxRemoveRoleBtn' class='remove-roles-btn' style='vertical-align:top;' /><br /><span id='ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl" + rolesCounterText + "_uxValTxtBoxRole' style='color:Red;visibility:hidden;'>Please complete this role requirement</span><br /><br /></div>");
        e.preventDefault();
        rolesCounter++;
        $('#ctl00_mainContent_uxTxtBoxRolesCount').val(rolesCounter);
    }));
```

So far so good. I hit the add button and the textbox appears, I type something in, everything's great. The html look something like this:

```
<div id="roles-0" class="div_row">
  <textarea id="ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl00_uxTxtBoxRole" cols="100" rows="5" name="ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl00$uxTxtBoxRole">Cool Job1</textarea><input class="remove-roles-btn" type="button" value="X" style="vertical-align:top;"><br><br>
</div>
<div id="roles-1" class="div_row">
  <textarea id="ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl01_uxTxtBoxRole" maxlength="2000" cols="100" rows="5" name="ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl01$uxTxtBoxRole">Test</textarea><input class="remove-roles-btn" type="submit" style="vertical-align:top;" value="X" name="ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl01$uxRemoveRoleBtn"><br><br>
</div>
```

Then I hit submit and the new values do not come through.

In the C# side I'm trying to access the data using:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in dl.Items)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox rb = item.FindControl(control) as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;

        if (rb.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            PositionRequirement pr = new PositionRequirement();
            pr.RequirementDescription = rb.Text;
            pr.RequirementLevel = new PositionRequirementLevel(level, levelDescription);
            pr.OrderNumber = i;
            i++;
            positionRequirements.Add(pr);
        }
    }
```

where dl = uxRolesList
control = uxTxtBoxRole

I'm at an utter loss as to why the new values are not coming through with the uxRolesList Repeater.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps while iterating the items of a repeater do check it the `RepeaterItem.ItemType`. It should be either `ListItemType.Item` or `ListItem.AlternatingItem`

Answer (score 0):

from what i know , the approach used is not going to show the items that are added within the Repeater Datasource, unless they exist before the page is being served to the user, so in the example, only the items that were bound to the repeater before leaving the server (if any) will show.

if you don't want to leave the page and make a trip to the server on every add click,of the top my head i would suggest that you would access them via the request Object using the name instead of the id ( Request[""] ) and keep the name of each textbox similar ("txtbox1","txtbox2")and append the count as you did in your Jquery code, then on the server when the page is submitted loop over the items using the counter that you have stored in uxTxtBoxRolesCount.